# Splitting URL using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to split the URL using JQuery and get a certain value, if that value is set I would display a certain 'div' corresponding with that value. Example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php#div1
```

I want to split the URL from the fragment identifier '#' and get the value coming after it 'div1'.

I then want to check using javascript/jquery if the value after the '#' is 'div1', I would display 'div1'.

```
var url = http://www.example.com/index.php#div1,
hash = url.split('#')[1];

if(hash == 'div1'){
$('.div1').show();
//if the hash is equal to 'div1' show the div with the class 'div1'
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What do you need?

Comment: It appears that you forgot to show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Consider spending more time attempting to write code yourself, rather than asking for what amounts to a work order.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm pretty sure the code he included in the question is what he tried

Comment: @WesFoster, that code isn't an attempt at solving the question OP asked.

Comment: @VitorLuizdaSilva I think it is quite obvious, I have explained it as much as I can, and I already got an answer.. Maybe read the question again ?

Comment: @zzzzBov yes I've attempted many times, and that's why I came here.. Could you please explain what a question is and what a work order because I'm clearly lost..

Comment: @WesFoster thank you, that's why I don't use stackoverflow that much. It's so hard to fit in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do a split, just use `location.hash` with an id

For example, given the URL `http://yoursite.com/page#div1`, the `location.hash` would return `#div1`. You can use this to select the proper element.

**ID Method:**

```
// JS
$(window.location.hash).show();

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="div1">Hidden</div>
```

**Class method:**

Alternatively, if you must use a class, you will need to remove the `#` from the `location.hash`

```
// JS
// The substr method removes the `#` from the beginning.
// You can just as easily use `replace`
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

$('.' + hash).show();

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="div1">Hidden</div>
```

Comment: the # is part of the hash

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the OP is using classes, not id.

Comment: Hey @Musa .. I have fixed the '#' problem appearing at the start, you can remove it using the substr(1); and it will remove the '#' only!

Comment: Thanks @Wes Foster I've figured it out, your solution was incomplete however! I have posted about it in a different reply!

Comment: @BeginnerP I had updated my answer at the exact same time you responded. :)